# Общие значения для нескольких графиков matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня есть 4 отдельных графика в одном окне, созданных с помощью библиотеки matplotlib. Можно ли задать для них одинаковые значения одновременно (например, для всех графиков одинаковые названия осей и наличие сетки)?
Я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде этого (сначала я прописывал отдельно значения, затем попробовал сделать словарь со значениями):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

...

````
values = {'colors': 'MediumSlateBlue, DarkTurquoise, ForestGreen, Gold'.split(", "), 'linewidth': 4,
          'labels': 'рентгеновское, видимое, инфракрасное, радио'.split(", "), 'grid': True, 'set_xlabel': 'частота',
          'set_ylabel': 'излучение'}
for i in axs:
    i.plot(values)```
````

Однако падает ошибка:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Можно. Можно, наверное, даже показать вам как именно, если вы переделаете свой вопрос в соответствии с рекомендациями сайта.

Comment: Ищите место где вы переписываете значение переменной `axs`.

Comment: `axs` видимо получается массив 2x2 и там можно двумя циклами его обойти, например.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, решение.
Извиняюсь за изначальные опечатки в тексте вопроса, о которых писали в комментариях.

Я решил задачу так:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]:
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_ylabel(# value)
    ax.set_xlabel(# value)
    # и другие значения
```